# Haskell fold over Data.Array

Tags: haskell

So I have a Data.Array array of tuples and I want to fold over it to get some final accumulator value. I can't use the traditional `foldr` and `foldl` so what is a good method/alternative to achieve the same result?

I tried to convert the array first to a list type using `elems` and `indices` but it doesn't work as expected because then I get a type error for my fold operation.

Note: I need both the array index and the array value in my computation for the accumulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need both the index and value, your best bet is to use the [`assocs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Array.html#v:assocs) :: `Array i e -> [(i, e)]` function to convert to the list of associations of an array in index order.  You can then fold over the resulting list like you normally do.

```
// array :: Array i e

result = foldr' acc initial_value (assocs array)
  where 
    acc :: (i,e) -> b -> b
    acc (i,e) value = // TODO
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you provide an example of how? Because Data.Array is (from what I understand) a tuple of (index, value). I need to reference both the index and the value in my computation of the accumulator. Sorry for not being clear earlier.